# How to read wire wrap labels?

Tags: wire, awg

This image is an example of a wire wrap label that lists multiple AWG numbers. 
What does it mean? How could it be anything but a single specific gauge?

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The part number (P/N B-30-1000) indicates it is AWG30 (and black and 305m = 1000').

The part number is printed onto a pre-printed 2-color label which contains the UL specification numbers and well as the brand. [UL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UL_(safety_organization)) is "a global safety consulting and certification company headquartered in Northbrook, Illinois. It maintains offices in 46 countries."

The relevant UL specification number in this case is [UL1423](http://www.wirefacts.com/web/ULSpec.aspx?Spec=UL1423) since it's AWG30. The standard is "Appliance Wiring Material UL 758".

That tells you (follow the link) that it's 105°C Polyvinylidene Fluoride (PVDF) Resin Insulated Wire, and provides some test parameters.

Comment: A detailed specification of similar material from another vendor is available at http://www.marmon-ad.com/_literature_159289/pvdf-insulated-singles

Comment: @davidmneedham The Chinese product might not be quite as good as the Marmon Aerospace product, of course. It's sold in China as 200m 0.25mm diameter core with the same part number.